# identity server 4 + oidc-client-js logout redirect

Tags: reactjs, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

I'm trying to implement OpenId and [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) in react. Right now I'm stuck in implementing logout function.

From what I understand, I need to set the `post_logout_redirect_uri` and use `signoutRedirect()` to logout the user. Logging out the user works, but unfortunately it stays in the identity server logout page. What I need to do is to redirect the user to the `post_logout_redirect_uri`.

Can someone tell me what am I missing here?  Thanks in advance!

This is the URL where I get redirected. `https://identityserver.xx.com/Account/Logout?logoutId=CfDJ8Cqm6alCoddAqWl...`

**Here's my tech stack:**

- [Identity Server v4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4)
- [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js)
- ReactJS (TS) with mobx state manager.

**Below is my Identity server admin settings.**

- Front Channel Logout Uri: http://localhost:3000/signout-oidc
- Post Logout Redirect Uris: http://localhost:3000/signout-callback-oidc

**Here's the logout code**

```
    logout = async () => {
        try {
            userManager.signoutRedirect({
                id_token_hint: this.user?.id_token,
                post_logout_redirect_uri : process.env.REACT_APP_LOGOFF_REDIRECT_URL,
                state: this.user?.state
            }).then( () => {
                console.log('done signoutRedirect')
            });

            userManager.clearStaleState()
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `AccountController` -> `BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync` method check `AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut` is true when constructing the viewmodel.

```
  var vm = new LoggedOutViewModel
            {
                AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut = AccountOptions.AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut, //this must return true.
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = logout?.PostLogoutRedirectUri,
                ClientName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(logout?.ClientName) ? logout?.ClientId : logout?.ClientName,
                SignOutIframeUrl = logout?.SignOutIFrameUrl,
                LogoutId = logoutId
            };
```

in your view `LoggedOut.cshtml` check `~/js/signout-redirect.js` is included properly.

```
@section scripts
{
    @if (Model.AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut)
    {
        <script src="~/js/signout-redirect.js"></script>

    }
}
```

if your logged out page doesn't contain anchor tag with `<a id="post-logout-redirect-uri" ...>` you probably have mismatching `post_logout_redirect_uri` configured in request and client.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The Identity server seems to work fine.  not sure if this loggedout.cshtml is relevant to my issue. I'm sending this request from a react service...

Comment: can you check the HTML(F12) for the logged out page to see if it contain the anchor tag and js I mentioned?

Comment: it has the signout-redirect.js but there's no anchor tag. It also contains an iframe that loads the logout callback page...

Comment: then probably mismatching postlogoutredirects in your client settings and identityserver registered client

Comment: check [ClientPostLogoutRedirectUris] table in the identity server and it should match exactly to your configured postlogoutredirect uri. check scheme and trailing '/'

Comment: http://localhost:3000/signout-callback-oidc doesn't look like the URL you want the user to redirect. Probably you want to land on the home page _http://localhost:3000/. So set it as so and make sure the identity server table has the exact uri.

Comment: I think your suspicion is correct, I'm trying to debug IDS server and found out that `post_logout_redirect_uri` always returns null. This might be the case. Thanks for pointing me to this direction.